# Sending and receiving a signal at the same time

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, multiprocessing

I’m working in python on a raspberry pi. I’m trying to send out a signal on a motor controller, and then receive a signal with a sensing hat after it pass through my plant (an RC filter in this case).

The important thing is I want to generate the output and read the input as close to simultaneously as possible. I was hoping to use multiprocessing to have a thread send the signal while the other read the incoming signal. But I keep getting confused on how threads work in python.

In short is it possible to do 2 different tasks with multiprocessing and then repeat those tasks (sending and reading a signal) until a condition is met. (like in a while loop)

(Edited with Code)

```
from __future__ import print_function
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
from adafruit_motorkit import MotorKit
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys
from sys import stdout
import numpy as np
from daqhats import mcc118, OptionFlags, HatIDs, HatError
from daqhats_utils import select_hat_device, enum_mask_to_string, \
    chan_list_to_mask
from decimal import *
import math
import time


getcontext().prec = 3

total_samples_read = 0
READ_ALL_AVAILABLE = -1
channelData = np.zeros(4, dtype=float)
CURSOR_BACK_2 = '\x1b[2D'
ERASE_TO_END_OF_LINE = '\x1b[0K'

# for plotting data
########################################
scan_rate = 1000 # scan rate in hz
maxtime = 30 # second s to run for
Datatime = np.zeros(maxtime * scan_rate, dtype=float)#List of times when smaples are taken
Data1 = np.zeros(maxtime * scan_rate, dtype=float) #sampels taken
data_index = 0 # Maximum index of data points taken
dt = Decimal(1 / scan_rate) # difference in time between indexes of Datatime
display_index = 0 # maximum index of Data being displayed on plot
#################################
# variables for Data logger
##########################
is_scanning = False
channels = [0]
channel_mask = chan_list_to_mask(channels)
num_channels = len(channels)
samples_per_channel = 0
options = OptionFlags.CONTINUOUS
######################################
startedTime = 0 # time at program start
myTime = 0 # time since program started


try:
    address = select_hat_device(HatIDs.MCC_118)
    hat = mcc118(address)
except (HatError, ValueError) as err:
    print('\n', err)


class MainWindow(pg.GraphicsWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(pg.GraphicsWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.delay = 30 #ms
        self.quit = QAction("Quit", self)
        self.quit.triggered.connect(self.clean_close)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(self.delay)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_plot)

    # plots data and runs calibrate between trials
    def update_plot(self):
        global display_index, Datatime, Data1
        kit.motor1.throttle = .4 + .2 * math.cos((time.time()-startedTime)* 2 * np.pi* 1) # 1hz sinusiod out of motor
        if data_index < len(Data1):
            Collect_Data()
        plot.setXRange(0, 20, padding=0)
        plot.setXRange(0, 20, padding=0)
        curve.setData(Datatime[:display_index], Data1[:display_index])
        display_index += 1
        app.processEvents()

    def clean_close(self):
        self.close()

# starts data collection
def Collect_Data():
    global is_scanning
    """
    This function is executed automatically when the module is run directly.
    """
    # Store the channels in a list and convert the list to a channel mask that
    # can be passed as a parameter to the MCC 118 functions.
    try:
        # Select an MCC 118 HAT device to use.

        # actual_scan_rate = hat.a_in_scan_actual_rate(num_channels, scan_rate)

        # Configure and start the scan.
        # Since the continuous option is being used, the samples_per_channel
        # parameter is ignored if the value is less than the default internal
        # buffer size (10000 * num_channels in this case). If a larger internal
        # buffer size is desired, set the value of this parameter accordingly.
        if not is_scanning:
            hat.a_in_scan_start(channel_mask, samples_per_channel, scan_rate,
                                options)
            is_scanning = True
        try:
            read_and_display_data(hat, num_channels)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            # Clear the '^C' from the display.
            print(CURSOR_BACK_2, ERASE_TO_END_OF_LINE, '\n')
            print('Stopping')
            hat.a_in_scan_stop()
            hat.a_in_scan_cleanup()

    except (HatError, ValueError) as err:
        print('\n', err)

# reads Data off of Hat and adds to Data1
def read_and_display_data(hat, num_channels):
    global channelData, data_index, Datatime, Data1
    
    total_samples_read = 0
    read_request_size = READ_ALL_AVAILABLE

    # When doing a continuous scan, the timeout value will be ignored in the
    # call to a_in_scan_read because we will be requesting that all available
    # samples (up to the default buffer size) be returned.
    timeout = 5.0

    # Read all of the available samples (up to the size of the read_buffer which
    # is specified by the user_buffer_size).  Since the read_request_size is set
    # to -1 (READ_ALL_AVAILABLE), this function returns immediately with
    # whatever samples are available (up to user_buffer_size) and the timeout
    # parameter is ignored.
    trigger = True
    while trigger == True:
        read_result = hat.a_in_scan_read(read_request_size, timeout)

        # Check for an overrun error
        if read_result.hardware_overrun:
            print('\n\nHardware overrun\n')
            break
        elif read_result.buffer_overrun:
            print('\n\nBuffer overrun\n')
            break

        samples_read_per_channel = int(len(read_result.data) / num_channels)
        total_samples_read += samples_read_per_channel
        # adds all data in buffer to data to be plotted.
        count = 0
        if samples_read_per_channel > 0:
            index = samples_read_per_channel * num_channels - num_channels
            while count < samples_read_per_channel:
                for i in range(num_channels):
                    channelData[i] = read_result.data[index + i]
                if data_index < len(Data1):
                    Data1[data_index] = channelData[0]
                    Datatime[data_index] = float(dt * Decimal(data_index))
                    data_index += 1
                    count += 1
            trigger = False
            stdout.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    win = MainWindow()  # display window
    plot = win.addPlot(1, 0)
    curve = plot.plot()
    win.show()
    kit = MotorKit() # implements motor driver
    kit.motor1.throttle = .4 # values 1 is 5v and 0 is 0 volts
    startedTime = time.time()
    # u = .2*math.cos(t * 2*np.pi*1)
    win.timer.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What sort of signal do you mean, please? Audio? Light? A software signal like a semaphore? How long does the signal stay on for? 1 millisecond or 4 minutes? How often do you need to sample it? Is it being sent and received on the same Raspberry Pi?

Comment: The signal is just a sinusoid voltage generated with with the motor controller, and I need to send it out for up to several minutes most likely. The hat has its own sampling rate and will sample it at whatever rate I set ( for now I’m using 1 KHz) I just need to continually check the hat and store the samples it receives in a numpy array. So in short task1: update sinusoid out, task2: pull read values from sensor.

Comment: I still don't understand, sorry. Please show your minimal code for sending a few samples/points of your signal. Also please show your minimal code for receiving some values from your sensor.

Comment: Still struggling :-( I can now see a lot of Qt GUI stuff and graphing, but your question seemed to be about generating a signal (which I don't see at all) and reading a sample (which I see but don't understand), and doing these two things in a closely synchronised manner. Please identify more clearly which two points in your code you are trying to keep close to each other. Thank you.

Comment: Your imports are super messy, and there are a ton of module level variables that do not appear to be constants. I'd suggest cleaning up both of these areas before worrying about threading (if you want a more thorough code review, please post it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: ok i'll comb it over thank you for the feedback